# global catch all java Exceptions in JRuby Sinatra app

Tags: jruby, sinatra

Im implementing a rest api with sinatra and jruby. The application domain is implemented in java. I have not figured out how to catch all exceptions thrown by the java layer in Sinatra. the global 'error do ... end' does not catch my java exception.

Any hints would be appreciated
/floda